# combining matrices with R

Tags: r, matrix

I have three matrices

```
id.df 

        column1   column2   column3   column4
 row1         1         2         3         4
 row2         5         6         7         8
 row3         9        10        11        12

names.df

        column1   column2   column3   column4
 row1         A         B         H         K
 row2         C         D         I         L
 row3         F         G         J         M

data.df

        column1   column2   column3   column4   column5  column6
 row1         1         4        8         4      5         1
 row2         5         8        7         8      3         5
 row3         4         7        5         1      7         4
```

I want to match `id.df` and `name.df` according to both row and col, which means that each value in `id` is corresponding to a name in `name.df`. Then I want to create a matrix D showing which name is corresponding to which `id`
e.g. 1:A 2:B 3:H 4:K 5:c 6:D 7:I 8:L ...

Last I want to replace the `id` in `data.df` with the name.

output:

replace the number in data.df with the names according to matrix D

```
  column1   column2   column3   column4   column5  column6
row1   A         K         L         K       C         A
row2   C         L         I         L       H         C
row3   K         I         C         A       I         K
```

NOTE: data.df is not the same dimensions with the other two.

Comment: Fixed the values now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datasets as mentioned in the description are `matrices`, then we can `match` the 'data.df' and 'id.df' to get the numeric index, use that to get the corresponding elements from 'names.df' to create a new matrix 'D'.

```
 D <- data.df
 D[] <- names.df[match(data.df, id.df)]
 D
 #    column1 column2 column3 column4
 #row1 "A"     "K"     "L"     "K"    
 #row2 "C"     "L"     "G"     "L"    
 #row3 "F"     "G"     "K"     "M"
```

#### Update

For the new dataset i.e. 'data.df1', we can use the same code

```
 D <- data.df1
 D[] <- names.df[match(data.df1, id.df)]
 D
 #    column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
 #row1 "A"     "K"     "L"     "K"     "C"     "A"    
 #row2 "C"     "L"     "I"     "L"     "H"     "C"    
 #row3 "K"     "I"     "C"     "A"     "I"     "K"
```

Or another option without the `match`

```
  D[] <- setNames(c(names.df), c(id.df))[as.character(data.df1)]
```

We create a `vector`  (`c(names.df)`) and set the names as 'id.df' (`c(id.df)`) as a 'key/value' pair.  The `vector` (`as.character(data.df1)`) will be matched with the 'key' and we get the corresponding 'value'.

NOTE: If the datasets are 'data.frame', it should be converted to 'matrix' for this to work. i.e. `names.df <- as.matrix(names.df)`, similarly for 'data.df' and 'id.df'.

#### data

```
 data.df <- structure(c(1L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 12L
 ), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3"), c("column1", 
 "column2", "column3", "column4")))

 id.df <-  structure(c(1L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 12L
 ), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3"), c("column1", 
 "column2", "column3", "column4")))

 names.df <- structure(c("A", "C", "F", "B", "D", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
  "K", 
 "L", "M"), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3"
 ), c("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4")))

 data.df1 <- structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L,
  5L, 
 3L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Dim = c(3L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("row1", 
 "row2", "row3"), c("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", 
 "column5", "column6")))
```

Comment: it said "undefined columns selected"

Comment: @Lucia Can you try with the dput output in my post

Comment: yes, I convert all of them into matrices. This time the output is all NA in data.df

Comment: @Lucia Try with the data in my post.  I am not getting any NAs

Comment: Ya, your data works well. I'll try to figure out what's the problem in my data. PS: data.df is not the same dimensions with the other two, do I need to change it?

Comment: What if data.df is not the same dimensions with the other two?

Comment: @Lucia It works with your edited dataset as well.  Please check my updates.